# Is there a way to filter/sort your questions by whether you have accepted an answer on your profile page?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, search

Every so often I like to go through my questions and make sure I haven't forgotten to accept an answer on each of them. However, when you have more than a few pages worth of questions it can be kind of cumbersome to page through them all and find the ones you still have outstanding (without an accepted answer).

Is there a way to sort or filter the questions on your profile page by whether or not they have an accepted answer? If not, I'd like to submit that as a feature request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find your questions without accepted answers with a search:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0

Or `user:me hasaccepted:0` in the search box.

Comment: You can also use `user:me` and it'll auto-plug-in your user id for the search :)