# Allow to see the questions with unaccepted answers in the user's profile

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, answers, profile-page, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to filter/sort your questions by whether you have accepted an answer on your profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79567/is-there-a-way-to-filter-sort-your-questions-by-whether-you-have-accepted-an-answ)

Sometimes, you ask a question for which the answer needs some testing before accepting it, and during that time, you may ask other questions. That question starts to move down in your question list, until you just forget it, even if a good answer had been provided.

It would be great to have, in the user's profile, a filter on the questions list that would allow to display only the questions without an accepted answer.